# Visual Studio suggesting fully qualified namespaces when not needed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

With Visual Studio 2010 (possibly 2008 as well) I am noticing behavior where Intellisense will suggest the fully qualified namespace for enums.

For example, I can write code like this:

```
element.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
element.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
```

But when I try to write it, it suggests I write it like this:

```
element.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
element.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
```

This unnecessary extra code can really add up and makes it less readable, and I have to basically fight with Intellisense to avoid it.

Is there I reason for this?  Can I just turn it off?  I assume the reason is that the name of the enum is the same as the name of the property.  But that's really not a good reason.

**EDIT:**

Here's another example that demonstrates why fully qualified naming is not necessary.

```
using SomeOtherNamespace;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class2 Class2 { get; set; }

        public Class1()
        {
            // These all compile fine and none require fully qualified naming.  The usage is context specific.
            // Intellisense lists static and instance members and you choose what you wanted from the list.

            Class2 = Class2.Default;
            Class2.Name = "Name";
            Class2.Name = Class2.Default.Name;
            Class2 = Class2;
        }
    }
}

namespace SomeOtherNamespace
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public static Class2 Default { get; set; }

        // public static Class2 Class2;  (This throws an error as it would create ambiguity and require fully qualified names.)

        // public static string Name { get; set; }  (This also throws an error because it would create ambiguity and require fully qualified names.

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Intrresting; VS has never suggested fully qualified names when not required, to my recollection.

Comment: I had the same issue previously in a Windows Forms application.  It was suggesting I write System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK instead of just DialogResult.OK.  Again, I'm pretty sure it's the fact that there is a local property named "DialogResult" in that scope (a Form).

Comment: right. I would consider it to be required in such a situation.

Comment: It's not required because of the context, for the same reason that You can make a property called "public Image Image".  Writing "DialogResult = DialogResult.OK" compiles fine because there is no ambiguity.  Writing it as "DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK" is not necessary.

Comment: To Intellisense, all it is concerned about (knows about) at *that moment* is DialogResult, and that would be ambiguous at that moment. It only becomes otherwise when you add more to it.

Comment: Intellisense is smarter than that, which is why this behavior is not present in Visual Studio 2005.  It knows there are two possibilities to how you use the term DialogResult and neither require a fully qualified name.  The person who offered an answer said it doesn't behave like this for him so it seems like a bug ("feature") in my version but I can't figure out how to disable it.  Going to try Visual Studio 11...

Comment: Visual Studio 11 has the same "feature".

Comment: Your edit shows a similar situation in terms of the code - but I can't see Intellisense having a problem with it - is it fully qualifying things in your code?

Comment: Yes, in both examples Intellisense prefixes the fully qualified namespaces and I have to type the first few letters to ignore the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This indeed seems to be the same name for property & the type.
Here is the smallest reproducible example that mimics things (could be smaller but this reveals more)...

```
namespace Company.Project.SubProject.Area.Test.AndSomeMore
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
        public TestEnum TestEnum { get; set; }
        public SndTestEnum NewEnum { get; set; }
    }
    public enum TestEnum
    {
        None,
        One,
        Two
    }
    public enum SndTestEnum
    {
        None,
        One,
        Two
    }
}
namespace MyCallerNS
{
    public class MyTestClass : TestClass
    {
        public MyTestClass()
        {
            this.TestEnum = Company.Project.SubProject.Area.Test.AndSomeMore.TestEnum.One;
            this.MyEnum = Company.Project.SubProject.Area.Test.AndSomeMore.TestEnum.Two;
            this.NewEnum = SndTestEnum.None;
        }
    }
}
```

Both `MyEnum` and `TestEnum` properties (targetting `TestEnum` enum) offer 'fully qualified' names (other has different name than its property type but the type matches other property's name, so both are 'tainted') - while SndTestEnum has different naming (for type, property) and works fine in either case.

...funny thing is that even if you remove `namespace MyCallerNS` and put all under the 'long namespace' - it'd still add `AndSomeMore.` in front.

There is not solution as I see it (short of Re# and 3rd party tools),
this seems to be the IntelliSense not being as smart as the compiler case, as @Rick suggested.

Or rather - compiler takes its time to resolve things (with all the info at hands), while IntelliSense does not have that 'depth' and insight into things (I'm guessing, simplifying really - we need @Eric on this:) and makes fast/easiest choices sort of.

Actually, on my previous thought,
it's more about the 'job' that each perform - and IntelliSense (as a completion 'service') has to present you with all the choices (both the property name and the type) in the list (I don't see them both being present, but a guess. And having one choice to cover both would probably be a pain to handle)
So to differentiate it adds the fully qualified names.
And where it 'fails' (sort of) is to 'paste' the 'short version' in the end - which indeed it should I think.

Answer (score 6):

I *suppose* you are working in WPF environment (I see element) and you have *somehow* the reference to `System.Windows.Forms` dll.

My deduction is based on fact that `HorizontalAlignment` can be found in both namespaces:

in [System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.horizontalalignment.aspx)

and

in [System.Windows.FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Having two references pointing to the same type, VS asks to specify what namespace *exactly* you mean.

Comment: I don't have a reference to System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: @Moozhe: any `Office` dlls, instead ?

Comment: It's an empty project with System, WindowsBase, PresentationFramework, and PresentationCore.

Comment: That's not the behavior I would get anyway.  If you try referencing System.Windows.Forms and then add a "using" the code I wrote wouldn't even compile due to ambiguity.

Comment: @Moozhe: correct, but I didn't know if the code provided even compilable, that's why I had the doubt like that.

Comment: @Moozhe: so if you add a `using System.Windows` on top of CS file, you will get, **by the way**, from VS a error to change to full name?

Comment: I already have "using System.Windows".  I'm not getting an error, I'm getting a suggestion which is a bad and annoying suggestion.

Comment: the suggession, just knowing the meaning of word "suggession" is about maintaining the fully qualified name, cause its just a *good practice to have it so*  and nothing else.

Comment: In many cases these suggestions make simple, readable lines of code into multi line monstrosities, sometimes increasing the size of a single statement by more than 500%.  No, I diagree, that's NOT good practice.

Comment: @Moozhe: I *suppose* you have something installed on your VS. Do you have some plugins installed that runs and influence in any way a compilation?

Comment: @Moozhe: I just tried on my simple project and it doesn't do anything like happens on your side.

Comment: No extensions installed.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1.

Answer (score 2):

I find if I type `element.HorizontalAlignment =` then VS2010 will automatically suggest `System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment` which will be selected if you press the tab key.  If instead of pressing the tab key you type 'Ho' to narrow the list, and then press tab, you will just get HorizontalAlignment.

If you are able to use [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), then after typing '= ' you will be presented with the most obvious choices of:

```
HorizontalAlignment.Center
HorizontalAlignment.Left
HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
HorizontalAlignment.Right
```

Comment: This may well be the right answer.  I actually researched this problem and found other people saying that Resharper did not fix the issue, but that could have been an older version or bad information.  I will try this tonight.

Comment: I'm using R# 6.1 and 7.  I can't remember what the behaviour used to be in previous version.

Comment: I tried R# 6.1 an 7.  Interestingly, it breaks the default Intellisense preselecting.  Under Resharper Options -> Environment -> Intellisense -> Autopopup -> C# it mentions Preselecting as an option, but it does not preselect, in fact the behavior seems identical even if you choose "Display and do not preselect".

Comment: Without preselecting, you need to either move a hand to the mouse to click, or move your hand to the arrow keys.  For enums I'm used to not having to take my hands off the home row.  For example, typing HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center should only take 2  keystrokes to select without leaving the home row typing position.  You need only type a Period and then a 'C'.

Comment: Yes, agreed.  It's annoying that R# doesn't take the Period into account inside an enum.  However you can use camel humps intellisense. e.g. type '= HAC' or '= HAT'.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where the compiler is smarter than Intellisense.

If you're accessing a property with the same name as its type, e.g. "public TextAlignment TextAlignment { get; set; }", you don't need to fully qualify the namespace of the enum value being assigned to it. But, Intellisense doesn't seem smart enough to know this. The code will work fine without the qualification, you just have to get good at noticing and dodging Intellisense.

Comment: Are you saying Intellisense in Visual Studio 2005 is smarter than Intellisense in VS 11?  I use VS2005 at work and I've never had this problem, not once.

Comment: I don't know? I'm haven't used 2005 since 2008.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, I have had some projects where Microsoft Office Automation was involved. My classes were structured as

- `CustomNameSpace.Library.Microsoft.Word.CustomClass1`
- `CustomNameSpace.Library.Microsoft.Excel.AnotherCustomClass`

When trying to access anything within the Microsoft namespace of .NET framework itself, Intellisense would force you to fully qualify names. In cases of root conflict it would also pre-pend the global keyword like so: `global::Windows.Forms.etc...`.